# Nested objects containing array in the Elements API plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-elementapi

I have an object `look` which contains an object categories from type of `array`. Currently I have to do the following to display the categories proper in the response.

```
'endpoints' => [
        'looks.json' => [
            'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => ['section' => 'looks'],
            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {

                // Create an array of all the photo URLs
                $categories = [];
                foreach ($entry->categories as $category) {
                    $object = (object) ['id' => $category->id, 'title' => $category->title];
                    $categories[] = $object;
                }
                return [
                    'title' => $entry->title,
                    'id' => $entry->id,
                    'categories' => $categories
                ];
            },
        ]
    ]
```

Is there a more elegant way to doing this? Especially because I'll have a lot of more cases where I have to deal with arrays in objects and arrays in objects and so on.

A structure could looks something like this

```
[
    {
      name: "ads"
      categories: [
         {
            name: "asdasda"
            subCategories: [
                name: "asdasdsa"
           ]
          }
      ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems a bit unnecessary to cast it to an object.  This should work identically:

```
'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {

    // Create an array of all the photo URLs
    $categories = [];

    foreach ($entry->categories as $category) {
        $categories[] = ['id' => $category->id, 'title' => $category->title];
    }

    return [
        'title' => $entry->title,
        'id' => $entry->id,
        'categories' => $categories
    ];
},
```